# Searching specific "Source", Find "Folder" & Deleting from multiple directories by setting paths

Tags: batch-file

I need some assistance trying to sort this out. What I am trying to attempt is to set a UNC `%sourcepath%` in which I can search a specific `%Folder%` and permanently delete it. This is what I've come up with so far, but I can't seem to get it working, just partially.

I will give you an example: I need to search for a folder called 2014 which collects images. This folder is broken down within 11 other folders. This process happens once a year. So I would like to be able to simply change the year so that the directories with the same name get permanently delete. So it has to "Search", Find and Delete those folders located within the UNC path. I tired what you send me, but it did not work. –

```
@echo %pause%off
REM if %pause%x==pausex set 
Set "Sourcepath=\\IP Address\directory\"
Set "folder=foldername"
%pause%
for /d /r "%sourcepath%" %%a in (%folder%) do if exist "%%a" echo rmdir /s /q "%%a"
%pause%
:END
```

Comment: You don't tell us how it is failing to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? I'd suggest `for /d /r` has difficulty with UNC paths.

How about

```
if exist "%sourcepath%\%folder%" echo rmdir /s /q "%sourcepath%\%folder%"
```

Comment: Can you even have a `for /d /r` loop?

Comment: @SomethingDark. Yes - it recursively lists directories matching mask from the specified root.

Comment: I will give you an example: 
I need to search for a folder called 2014 which collects images. This folder is broken down within 11 other folders. This process happens once a year. So I would like to be able to simply change the year so that the directories with the same name get permanently delete. So it has to "Search", Find and Delete those folders located within the UNC path. 

I tired what you send me, but it did not work.

Comment: @CarlosMarion-Landais, why not including this extra information in your question?

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion.